# Как вставить html в quill что бы редактор не добавлял tag p

Tags: javascript, html

Я получаю html файл и мне его надо вставить в редактор Quiil

В интернете и из документации нашёл следующий способ

```
editor['obj']['editor']['quill'].root.innerHTML = target.querySelector('.preview').innerHTML
```

Html Вставляется но он вставляет ещё сверху и снизу по тегу

Следующего вида

```
<p></p>
    <p>
    My code
    </p>
<p></p>
```

Как мне вставить свой html в редактор без этого тега  ?

Я пробовал вставлять в .ql-editor но результат тот же

```
editor['varan-editor'][i]['obj']['this'].querySelector('.ql-editor').innerHTML =  target.querySelector('.preview').innerHTML
```

Comment: Что если решить в лоб? `el = editor['obj']['editor']['quill'].root` несколько раз подняться по дереву, `el.parentElement` (столько сколько нужно)... Может сработает?

Comment: А я уже сталкивался с подобной проблемой.нашёл вчера в чём проблема.У меня редактор стили должен сохранять у меня pre wrap стоит. Дополнительные тегипоявлялись, потому что учитывались пробелы в самом шаблоне. Что бы от них избавиться достаточно теплейн экранировать     --></div><!--  и проблема исчезла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это может происходить из-за пробелов в самом шаблоне. 
Достаточно поставить экранирование темплейта.

html =             `

```
                     --><details class="adminMenu item_${i}" ><!--
                        --><div id="timestamp" style="display: none">${obj['data'][i]['timestamp']}</div><!--
                                              --><summary class="adminContent"><!--
                                              --><div class ="item"><!--
                                              --><div class="news"><!--
                                              --><h2><!--
                                                 -->${obj['data'][i]['title']}<!--
                                          --></h2><div class="short-content"><details><summary class="preview">${descr}</summary><div class="content">${cont}</div><!--
                                  --></details><!--
                                          --></div><!--
                                  --></div><!--
                                      --><div class="hexagon"><!--
                                           --><img  class="moderator" src="${obj['data'][i]['img']}" alt="moderator"><!--
                                      --></div><!--
                                  --></div><!--
                                              --></summary><!--
                                  --><div class="menu"><!--
                                              --><button class="delete"> удалить </button><!--
                                              --><button class="change"> редактировать </button><!--
                                  --></div><!--
                          --></details><!--

                            `
```